# Swift: Cell Contents Shifting Down on each UITableView Reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am dequeuing a custom prototype tableview cell and setting the variables in cellforrowatindexpath. Initial load of the cell though has the cell contents shifted above the table's top border. And each table reload shifts my cell's contents down slightly. After 5-6 reloads, the cell's contents finally shift down into their correct place, and it looks as if it should.

Here's my code. This problem does not happen unless I add a SetView as a subview to my cell, as shown in the below code. In storyboard, I have a prototype ViewExerciseCellWithSets that includes (i) a top view with some labels and images; and (ii) a bottom view that serves as a set view container for the SetView. The bottom view has an auto layout constraint with a top space = 0 relative to the top view. To be clear, the "bottom view" as I refer here is cell.setViewContainer in the below code.

If I don't add a SetView, all other labels, images, etc. in the cell are in their proper place from the first cell load and stay that way. Any ideas?

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("viewExerciseCellWithSets", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ViewExerciseCellWithSets

            if (showSets) {
                for (var i=0; i < sets.count; i++ ) {
                   var frameStart = (x: CGFloat(0),y: CGFloat(0))
                    frameStart = getXYStartThreeColumns(i)
                    let  setView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("StrengthSetView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! StrengthSetView
                    setView.frame = CGRectMake(frameStart.x, frameStart.y, CGFloat(170), CGFloat(30))
                    cell.setViewContainer.addSubView(setView)
                 }
             }
      }


func getXYStartThreeColumns(i:Int) -> (x:CGFloat , y:CGFloat) {
    let multiplier:Int = i/3
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        return (CGFloat(0), CGFloat(multiplier*30))
    }
    else if (i % 3 == 1) {
        return (CGFloat(100), CGFloat(multiplier*30))
    }
    else {
        return (CGFloat(200), CGFloat(multiplier*30))
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of i?

Comment: The number of sets to be added. It is therefore the number of SetViews to be added, with one SetView being added for each set. I just add the SetViews to different places in the setviewcontainer to create a three column format. I might be adding them wrongly though?

Comment: When the cell loads, the top view and the bottom view appear as if they are overlapping and violating the auto layout constraints. But after 5 cell reloads they are in the correct places. Again, only happens when I add SetViews.

Comment: Seems to me that the frame calculation for the setView might have some problems. How many sets are added? Is it always 3 or less or more than 3? Note that if you are adding 3 columns then the frame's top position will be 30. But I presume you want 3 columns to appear alongside each other. So you could change i/3 to i/4 and try so that the 4th column goes to the next line and 3 columns are always on the same row.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I should have put the for loop in to loop through i. That shows i starts at 0, not 1. So i is more of an index to the set number (starting at 0), looped through the number of sets to be added. I have edited the post to clarify this. With this clarification, you'll find adding 3 columns keeps them on the same line I think, with the 4th going to the next line. To answer your question, i can be anything, 3, less than 3, or more than 3.

Comment: Are you using the cell's contentView to add your custom controls?

Comment: Yes, both top and bottom views are subviews of the cell's content view

Comment: Also, the problem happens no matter the number of sets. It happens even for a single set or SetView added